# While condition only respected if I put while 1 and put an if and break with the same condition

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

This is a part of a code that do a binary search in an array.

```
int arrayBinary_search(myarray[], key){

    int selector = 0;
    int low_limit = 0;
    int high_limit = SIZE;
    while (1){
        selector = (low_limit+high_limit)/2;
        printf("The selector is: %d\n", selector);
        if (myarray[selector] == key){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            if (low_limit==selector || high_limit==selector)        // this is the condition
                break;
            if (key < myarray[selector])
                high_limit = selector;
            else
                low_limit = selector;
            printf("The high_limit is: %d\n", high_limit);
            printf("The low_limit is: %d\n", low_limit);
        }

    }

}
```

The code works, but since is not recommended to put a while(1), I wanted to insert the condition `low_limit==selector || high_limit==selector` directly inside the while condition replacing that "1".

So this should be:

```
int arrayBinary_search(myarray[], key){

    int selector = 0;
    int low_limit = 0;
    int high_limit = SIZE;
    while (!(low_limit==selector) && !(high_limit==selector)){        // this is the condition implemented
        selector = (low_limit+high_limit)/2;
        printf("The selector is: %d\n", selector);
        if (myarray[selector] == key){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            //if (low_limit==selector || high_limit==selector)
            //  break;
            if (key < myarray[selector])
                high_limit = selector;
            else
                low_limit = selector;
            printf("The high_limit is: %d\n", high_limit);
            printf("The low_limit is: %d\n", low_limit);
        }

    }

}
```

Because that condition should correspond to a NEGATED OR, which is two negated entries with AND.

But, it doesn't work.

Full code here: https://hastebin.com/cebaxicasu.cpp

Comment: The function definition of `arrayBinary_search` do not have parameter types only parameter identifiers which is a compiler error on its own.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio actually the compiler gives me warnings not errors about that. Btw, you are right and I have to add the type

Comment: I do not know which compiler you use, but gcc treats that as error without any additional flag. BTW, you shall never ignore compiler warnings unless you know to 100%  that they are redundant (but the cases of this are rare).

Comment: I tried it with clang now and it indeed gives only warnings about that - interesting - so I guess you compile with clang. You shall never omit function parameter types anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The value of variable selector is initialised as follows,

```
 int selector = 0;
```

Due to this your program will never enter the while loop because, `!(low_limit==selector)` is always false.

The following changes will make your code work properly.

```
int arrayBinary_search(int myarray[], int key){
    int selector;
    int low_limit = 0;
    int high_limit = SIZE;
    while (low_limit <= high_limit){
        selector = (low_limit+ high_limit)/2;
        printf("The selector is: %d\n", selector);
        if (myarray[selector] == key){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            if (key < myarray[selector])
                high_limit = selector-1;
            else
                low_limit = selector+1;
            printf("The high_limit is: %d\n", high_limit);
            printf("The low_limit is: %d\n", low_limit);
        }

    }

}
```

Also notice that your function prototypes should have parameter types as shown below.

```
int arrayGenerator(int myarray[]);
int arrayBinary_search(int myarray[], int key);
```

Comment: ... or alternatively, a `do { ... } while()` loop might be would be more appropriate, so that the loop condition is not evaluated before the first iteration.

Comment: You are right but... the program doesn't work as I expected. Because yes, now it enteres in cycle, but it does only one cylce since it block immidietely because "selector" has the same value of "high_limit" after the first cycle.

Comment: The following while loop is required   'while (low_limit <= high_limit)'